# Type parameters applied to Scala Function

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I am trying to understand the type parameters when applied to a function.

I would like to use Generic Types in the  below method but using String and Int for my understanding.

When I define a function as below

```
  def myfunc[Int](f:String => Int):Int =  {
    Integer.min(1,2)
  }
```

it complains

```
 found   : scala.this.Int
 required: Int&0
      Integer.min(1,2)
```

However if I remove the return type of the function ( which I understand is not required), it compiles fine.

I am not able to infer why removing the return type makes the compilation successful.

Appreciate your help.

-Amit

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
def myfunc(f:String => Int):Int =  {
  Integer.min(1,2)
}
```

When you write `def myfunc[Int](f:String => Int):Int` you declare type parameter `Int`, which hides standard type `scala.Int`. This is the same as if you declared `def myfunc[A](f:String => A):A`. When you remove return type it's inferred to be `scala.Int`, i.e. `def myfunc[A](f:String => A)` is `def myfunc[A](f:String => A):Int`

Comment: Yeah, it did work when I removed the return type and that is where I got confused and hence posted the question. Maybe this is what I am failing to understand -  "you declare type parameter Int, which hides standard type scala.Int"

Comment: @Amit you hide it for your own use, but the compiler does know the fully qualified name of the type. For example, you may use `_root_scala.Int` as the return type, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use generics, first you have to understand that the name of the variable types starts capitalized and they are names, just that so `[Int]` in your function is the name of the type variable, an example:

```
object Main extends App{
    val f: String => Int = s => 4
    println(myfunc(f, "nothing useful"))

    def myfunc[A,B](f:A => B, x: A):B =  {
      f(x)
    }
}
```

here the names are `A` and `B` and the return type is of type `B`

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: What's the difference between these 3 methods?

```scala
def myfunc1[X](f:String => X):X =
  Integer.min(1,2)

def myfunc2[Int](f:String => Int):Int =
  Integer.min(1,2)

def myfunc3[IDontGetTypeParameters](f:String => IDontGetTypeParameters):IDontGetTypeParameters =
  Integer.min(1,2)
```

**Answer**: Nothing. From the compiler's point of view they are the same, and they fail to compile for the same reason: each is defined to return the type of the type parameter but tries to return an integer (`Scala.Int`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one liner:

```
def myfunc(f:String => Int):Int = Integer.min(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good trying to make your own examples, but have you tried any examples from books, articles or tutorials? There's probably a good one in *Scala for the Impatient* by Cay Horstmann.

Here's a decent example [from the Tour de Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html):

```
def listOfDuplicates[A](x: A, length: Int): List[A] = {
  if (length < 1)
    Nil
  else
    x :: listOfDuplicates(x, length - 1)
}
```

Sometimes you can omit the type parameter, but let's ignore that for now and declare the types explicitly:

```
listOfDuplicates[Int](43, 5) // Should give a list with 43 five times
listOfDuplicates[String]("Hello, world! ", 3) // "Hello, world!" thrice
listOfDuplicates[(Int, Int)]((0, 1), 8) // The pair (0, 1) eight times
```

This shows that `A` can be `Int`, `String`, `(Int, Int)` or just about anything else we can think of. Not sure you'd ever have a practical need for this, but you can even do something like this:

```
def wrapLength(str: String): Int = str.length

listOfDuplicates[String => Int](wrapLength(_), 2)
```

Here's [a Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/68TfNTr7RhO8Ymbe8pmjgw) in which you can play around with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your generic type name shouldn't be one of the reserved words in Scala. Int itself is a reserved word for a type. 
In this cases, for simplicity and understanding, we use some basic characters like T or R as the generic type if you really keen to use generics for other functions.